# Problems Implementing Infection Dynamics in Agent-Based Model with Julia's Agents.jl Package

Tags: julia, agent-based-modeling

Thank you in advance to everyone who reads through this. I have no idea how to make this shorter in order to explain my problem. I also apologize for the vague title, as I have no idea where the root of this problem lies.

I created an Agent Based Model using Julias [Agents.jl](https://juliadynamics.github.io/Agents.jl/stable/) package, consisting of 5 Agents. For this question, 3 are relevant: Sticklebacks, Copepods and Parasites. Lifecycle as follows: Parasites infect copepods -> Stickleback prey on infected Copepods and therefore get infected themselves. The agents are realised as a mutable struct (Abstract Agents) with certain fields - one of which is the infection status.

```
mutable struct CopepodGrazerParasitePhytoplankton <: AbstractAgent
    id::Int
    pos::NTuple{2, Float64}
    type::Symbol
    infected::Int   # 0 = false, 1 = true
end
```

The Sticklebacks prey upon Copepods (infected and uninfected) and eventually get infected themselves. My Problem:

I can't get the Sticklebacks to get infected while simultaneously continue the "normal hunt" of Copepods. This is my current stickleback_eat! function:

```
function stickleback_eat!(stickleback, model)
    infection = [inf_copepod for inf_copepod in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if inf_copepod.infected == 1]

    if !isempty(infection)
        stickleback.infected = 1
    end

    eat = [x for x in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if x.type == :copepod || x.type == :grazer]

    if !isempty(eat)
        for x in eat
            remove_agent!(x, model, model.pathfinder)
        end
    end
end
```

Stickleback_vision is set to 8 and is not changed on any iteration of the model.

Agents that are in the vicinity of the Stickleback get preyed upon and killed, but **no** infection of sticklebacks is seen whatsoever.

Weirdly, if I **remove** the eat part of the function (as in the following), the infection of Sticklebacks works perfectly (proven by logging and dataframes):

```
function stickleback_eat!(stickleback, model)
    infection = [inf_copepod for inf_copepod in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if inf_copepod.infected == 1]

    if !isempty(infection)
        stickleback.infected = 1
    end
```

But i also need the Sticklebacks to remove the copepods and grazers in its vicinity from the model.

Therefore what I've tried so far to fix this:

1. Splitting it up in multiple functions:

```
function stickleback_infection!(stickleback, model)
    infection = [y for y in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if y.infected == 1]
    if !isempty(infection)
        stickleback.infected = 1
        remove_agent!(y, model, model.pathfinder)
    end
end

function stickleback_eat!(stickleback, model)

    eat = [x for x in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if x.type == :copepod || x.type == :grazer]

    if !isempty(eat)
        for x in eat
            remove_agent!(x, model, model.pathfinder)
        end
    end
end
```

2. Having only one array and check for infection status while eating:

```
function stickleback_eat!(stickleback, model)

    eat = [x for x in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if x.type == :copepod || x.type == :grazer]
    if !isempty(eat)
        for x in eat
            if x.infected == 1
                stickleback.infected = 1
            end
            remove_agent!(x, model, model.pathfinder)
        end
    end
end
```

Both (and many other smaller) changes don't work and I feel like i'm having a big hole in understanding any of these structures, which i cant identify yet.
It's as if the *eat* part prohibits the infection of Sticklebacks and I just cant figure out why.
Thank you again for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, I don't have this issue extending GridAgents. For example, this code (which is pretty much identical to the original post with the exception of how the agent is defined) doesn't have an error:

```
using Agents
space = GridSpaceSingle((10, 10); periodic = false)

@agent simpleAgent GridAgent{2} begin
    type::Symbol
    infected::Int   # 0 = false, 1 = true
end

function stickleback_eat!(stickleback, model)
    infection = [inf_copepod for inf_copepod in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if inf_copepod.infected == 1]

    if !isempty(infection)
        stickleback.infected = 1
    end

    eat = [x for x in nearby_agents(stickleback, model, model.stickleback_vision) if x.type == :copepod || x.type == :grazer]

    if !isempty(eat)
        for x in eat
            remove_agent!(x, model)
        end
    end
end

properties = Dict(:stickleback_vision => 8)
model = ABM(simpleAgent, space; properties)

copepod1 = simpleAgent(1, (1.0, 1.0), :copepod, 0)
copepod2 = simpleAgent(3, (3.0, 3.0), :copepod, 1)
stickleback = simpleAgent(4, (10.0, 10.0), :stickleback, 0)

add_agent!(copepod1, model)
add_agent!(copepod2, model)
add_agent!(stickleback, model)

println("Stickleback infection: ", stickleback.infected)
println("Number of agents: ", nagents(model))
stickleback_eat!(stickleback, model)
println("Stickleback infection: ", stickleback.infected)
println("Number of agents: ", nagents(model))
```

The output here is:

```
Stickleback infection: 0
Number of agents: 3
Stickleback infection: 1
Number of agents: 1
```

which shows that the eating and the infection is done in the same step. For OP, I'd ask two questions: could you confirm this setup works in your installation, and share any other details that could help identify how the model setup is different?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.
1. Yes this setup works on my installation, i get the same exact output.
2. The only difference to my model is, that I am using a Continuous Space (100., 100.). But I don't see how that should pose a problem, especially since the infection works in the absence of "eating".

Comment: Hmm that is strange then - I agree that changing to a continuous space doesn't affect this (and double checked that using the same code). The only thing I can imagine is happening is that somehow eat is getting done before your infection update and that removes them from consideration for if the stickleback gets infected. However, that should be corrected by the single update loop you posted. Could you share a full MWE that reproduces the strange behavior you notice?

Comment: I tried, but the model is too complex to break it down (or rather it would take me too long to do so). I found a fix for my problem tho:

If i increase the vision radius of the Stickleback in my **stickleback_infection!** function (see Point 1.) by a modifier of only 1.01, both the infection and the _eating_ works fine. This suggests, that the collection of the "eat" array somehow prevents the infection array to be filled with agents. (I know this is not supposed to work, since its different functions and i **also** call the stickleback_infection! before stickleback_eat! ..) @crazyraptor

Comment: thank you very much for your help tho, I have a deadline to meet so I wont get to the bottom of this atm, but afterwards I'll try to figure out whats going on. If i do so, I will most certainly tag you. Cheers

Comment: Interesting haha....definitely seems like a bug of some sort - good luck on deadlines!